# Why does installed "igraph" package return "libicui18n.so.58: cannot open shared object file"after loading?

Tags: r, igraph

I was trying to install the package igraph in R using the command install.packages("igraph"). After the installation, during testing phase it showed the following error:

> testing if installed package can be loaded Error: package or namespace
> load failed for ‘igraph’ in dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...):
> unable to load shared object
> '/home/midhun/R/x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu-library/3.5/igraph/libs/igraph.so':
> libicui18n.so.58: cannot open shared object file: No such file or
> directory   Error: loading failed   Execution halted   ERROR: loading
> failed
>
> - removing ‘/home/midhun/R/x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu-library/3.5/igraph’
>
> The downloaded source packages are in
> ‘/tmp/RtmpLVDism/downloaded_packages’   Warning message:   In
> install.packages("igraph") :     installation of package ‘igraph’ had
> non-zero exit status

Why this is happening? What could be a solution?

Comment: See if this [Unix & Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/350364/firefox-libicui18n-so-58-cannot-open-shared-object-file) question solves the problem

Comment: This partially helped. The program required libicui18n.so.58 in 'usr/lib64' but it was installed elsewhere.

Answer (score 2):

The library `igraph` requires library files such as:

`libicui18n.so.58`, `libicuuc.so.58`, `libgfortran`, etc.

These were either not installed in the proper library folder or were existing as previous versions. For example, in my case, `libicuuc.so.58` was required to be installed in `usr/lib64`. Make sure that dependencies are installed correctly to solve such problems.