# Problem uploading "igraph" library on google cloud virtual R

Tags: r, google-cloud-platform, igraph

I am new to google cloud.
After installing the package"igraph" on a virtual R tool and trying to load it, I got the following messages:

[image]

Any suggestions for solving it?

Thank you so much

Comment: There could be many reasons as you are having provided error messages. I hope below links [1] and [2] could be helpful for you to troubleshoot the issue:

[1] https://github.com/igraph/rigraph/issues/213#issuecomment-322046503

[2] https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53238157/why-installed-igraph-package-in-r-is-showing-error-upon-loading

Comment: Thank you Shafiq

Answer (score 2):

On Ubuntu, it's usually easier to install the pre-built binaries from the [cran2deb4ubuntu Build Team PPA](https://launchpad.net/%7Ec2d4u.team/+archive/ubuntu/c2d4u4.0+) than using the `install()` command to install from source. In the image that `googleComputeEngineR` uses, this is already set up it seems (if you used something else to set up your instance your mileage might vary). So you should be able to get igraph by running the following commands in the Terminal (Not the Console!):

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install libglpk-dev
sudo apt install r-cran-igraph
```

First command makes sure you get the newest version, second one installs a dependency, third command installs the `igraph` package. I tested this on a fresh machine and it worked.

Comment: when I try this I get
_The following packages have unmet dependencies:
r-cran-igraph:
Depends: r-base-core (>= 3.5.2-1) but it is not going to be installed. 
Depends: r-api-3.5. 
Depends: r-cran-magrittr but it is not going to be installed. 
Depends: r-cran-matrix but it is not going to be installed. 
Depends: r-cran-pkgconfig (>= 2.0.0) but it is not going to be installed. 
Recommends: r-cran-testthat but it is not going to be installed. 
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages._
Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Sounds like you have a version of R that is so old, you can't install the packages. Try `sudo apt upgrade` to upgrade packages first. Then enter R to see which version you have. If that didn't help, google how to get the newest version of R on Ubuntu. This guide looks good: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-r-on-ubuntu-20-04